# num_rows property is never predictable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am really tired of this `num_rows` property. First I was using it without `store_result()` and it was not working. Then I found out that I should store the results locally in order to find out the number of records. It worked. Now it again stopped working.

When I check the property `RequestedId` it does return a value. However, `num_rows` says `zero`. What else am I missing?

```
  $query="select RequestedId from friend_request where RequestingId=?";
  $stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
  $stmt->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param('i',$requestinguserid);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($RequestedId);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
  {

    return $RequestedId;
 }
 else{
return 0;

}
```

Comment: execute -> store result -> num rows -> bind result -> fetch -> return, just follow the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the explanation on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

The `store_result` function needs to be called before you fetch.

```
$stmt->execute();

/* store result */
$stmt->store_result();

printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

/* free result */
$stmt->free_result();
```

You should be able to read the results prior to freeing them.

Comment: Thanks... I edited the code a while ago.. and it never ever for a single moment crossed my mind to put the `store_result` above the `fetch()`.. :(

Answer (score 2):

The flow is, prepare and execute the statement, then store the result, then check the number of rows, under your condition wherein its greater than zero, bind the result, then fetch after that, then return whatever value in that column you fetched:

```
$query = "select RequestedId from friend_request where RequestingId = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$requestinguserid);
$stmt->execute(); // execute
$stmt->store_result(); // store result

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) // check number of rows
{
    $stmt->bind_result($RequestedId); // bind result
    $stmt->fetch(); // fetch
    return $RequestedId; // return
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Another alternative is if you have `mysqlnd` driver on your environment, you can also utilize those pertinent methods and it does it the same way:

```
$query = "select RequestedId from friend_request where RequestingId=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); // prepared
$stmt->bind_param('i', $requestinguserid); // bind
$stmt->execute(); // execute
$results = $stmt->get_result(); // get result

if($results->num_rows > 0) { // check number of rows the from result
    $row = $results->fetch_row(); // fetch
    return $row[0]; // return
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Sidenote: If you're wondering what does that `$results` contain, it should show the following using `print_r`:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)
```

The `num_rows` property is derived from there.

Comment: Thanks Ghost... The first answer resolved my question so I accepted that as an answer.. However, your explaination is nice too.

Comment: @whatever sure, the first answer by Flosculus deserved the credit no prob with that, glad we clarified it.

Comment: @Ghost Thanks, BTH though, this one deserves the accept, as I don't personally use mysqli, my answer was more of an assumption.

Comment: @Flosculus Thank you buddy... I made my head spin for a while.. as to what is wrong again...